# How to implement oncompletionlistener to detect end of media file in Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to play videos in the form of a playlist one after another. I am using android ExoPlayer to play my files, but there are no listeners in ExoPlayer to listen to an end of a media file.

Is there a way to listen to the end of media files using ExoPlayer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Exoplayer offer advance implementation which media player do not.

in Advance example of [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo) by Android, in **[FullPlayerActivity.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/4bc79c9465abd00e29ff576c5f7a7517be632f5a/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L686)** they have implemented **onStateChanged**, which offers **STATE_ENDED**

You can download example from the right hand section of [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) under term **RELATED SAMPLES**

Comment: They have updated the sdk and samples, a little search will yield results. Btw I have updated the broken link.

Comment: Small detail It is onPlayerStateChanged. Possible they updated it.

Comment: When MediaSource is LoopingMediaSource, the STATE_ENDED event is not fired.

Answer (score 66):

I know this is old, but just to expand on the accepted answer:

```
exoPlayer.addListener(this);

.....

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int state) {

    if (state == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED){
        //player back ended
    }
}
```

Comment: `onPositionDiscontinuity()` is called in my case how to handle then?

Comment: It works when I stream online videos but onPlayerStateChanged will not call when I play video locally

Answer (score 37):

Google has deprecate `ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED` and has replaced with `Player.STATE_ENDED`.

Since this post has been a while, I will write a `Kotlin` version of the listener down below.

```kotlin
this.simpleExoPlayer?.addListener(object : Player.DefaultEventListener() {
    override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean,playbackState: Int) {
        when (playbackState) {
            Player.STATE_IDLE -> {}
            Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {}
            Player.STATE_READY -> {}
            Player.STATE_ENDED -> {}
        }
    }
})
```

**UPDATE: 05-2020**
Since `DefaultEventListener` and `onPlayerStateChanged()` are deprecated.

```kotlin
player.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
     override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
           if (state == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
              // your code
           }
     }
})
```

Comment: DefaultEventListener() is deprecated use instead    this.player?.addListener(object :Player.EventListener{
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                when (playbackState) {
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> {  progressBar.visibility=View.VISIBLE}

                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> { progressBar.visibility=View.VISIBLE }

                    Player.STATE_READY -> { progressBar.visibility=View.GONE}
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> { progressBar.visibility=View.GONE} }
            }
        })

Comment: seems like `EventListener` is also deprecated now, it seems to just need `Player.Listener` now

Answer (score 14):

**You can do this:**

```
playerExo.addListener(new ExoPlayer.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

                switch(playbackState) {
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                        //do what you want
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_PREPARING:
                        break;
                    case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }
        });
        playerExo.seekTo(0);
        playerExo.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

But @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain answer is right! Have a nice code day! Let me know if you need something else!

Comment: STATE_ENDED is getting called twice

Comment: check with playing video or not using player.getPlayWhenReady()

Comment: You can use `Player.DefaultEventListener()` where all interface methods are stubbed. So you can remove unneeded methods like `onPlayWhenReadyCommitted` and `onPlayWhenReadyCommitted`

Answer (score 11):

You have to implement the interface **Player.EventLister** and add to your exoPlayer.

Just write your code on the method **onPlayerStateChanged**. See the code.

```
exoPlayer.addListener( new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

                switch(playbackState) {
                    case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                        //Here you do what you want
                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_IDLE:
                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_READY:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }


        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Google has deprecate ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED. Use Player.STATE_ENDED instead. See the code below.

```
player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

        if (playWhenReady && playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
            // Active playback.
        } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
            //The player finished playing all media

           //Add your code here

        } else if (playWhenReady) {
            // Not playing because playback ended, the player is buffering, stopped or
            // failed. Check playbackState and player.getPlaybackError for details.
        } else {
            // Paused by app.
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
        //THIS METHOD GETS CALLED FOR EVERY NEW SOURCE THAT IS PLAYED
      //  int latestWindowIndex = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();


    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekProcessed() {

    }
});
```

You can check [ExoPlayer Developer page](https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

For non-concatenated MediaSource (representing whatever individual piece of media you want to play), you'll receive **STATE_ENDED** when the piece of media has finished playing.

For a ConcatenatingMediaSource it occurs when the entire concatenation has finished playing (i.e. you've played up to the end of the final item in the concatenation). So, STATE_ENDED occurs when the entire MediaSource has finished playing.

For a ConcatenatingMediaSource, the best callback to detect end of current media and start of next media playback is "onPositionDiscontinuity"
You should use **onPositionDiscontinuity()** to figure out when transitions occur. Please note, onPositionDiscontinuity is invoked for some other cases too, but you can call **getCurrentWindowIndex()** and compare it to what window you think you're in to determine whether a transition has occurred. You can do something like below:

```
public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
  int newIndex = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
  if (newIndex != currentIndex) {
    // The index has changed ==> last media has ended and next media playback is started.
    currentIndex = newIndex;
  }
}
```

**Please note:** onPositionDiscontinuity() is not gets called for the 1st item in the playlist unless we explicitly call player.seekTo(position,0). So to handle anything you are doing for all media playback in the playlist you have to handle separately for the 1st item in the playlist.

Comment: `onPositionDiscontinuity()` is called when the track is changed, but what if I want to do something right before it changes?

Comment: HI @SamChen, onPositionDiscontinuity is dispatched apparently after the first frame of the "next video" is already rendered. But I don’t think there is any such event available that could fire just before the first frame of the "next video" got rendered. But you could add a **VideoFrameMetadataListener** to the video renderer that calls a method on the rendering thread every time a frame is about to be released [link](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/video/VideoFrameMetadataListener.html)

Comment: @SamChen Found one discussion on this which may help [link] (https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6576)

Comment: Thank you, but what I mean is not the "next video", is the end of current video. I also created the post for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889341/android-exoplayer-playlist-pause-current-track-when-it-finishes.

Comment: @SamChen, I have posted a few options which you can try on your post. I hope that would help. Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED is depreciated. Use Player.STATE_ENDED instead.
Example:

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if(playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED){
        // your brain put here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using playlist with exoplayer and I wanted to stop the media after it was complete.

For me the **Player.STATE_ENDED** was being called when the playlist ended for me inside

So to fulfill my use case I first set this in exoplayer

```
 simpleExoPlayer.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
```

So instead of using **EventListener**,  I had used the **AnalyticsListener** which gives the **onPositionDiscontinuity** to override with eventTime parameter and just add a simple code to know whether the media has restarted.

```
   @Override
   public void onPositionDiscontinuity(EventTime eventTime, int reason) {
        if (eventTime.currentPlaybackPositionMs / 1000 < 1) {
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            tvReplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps your usecase

Comment: `onPositionDiscontinuity()` is called after the track has changed or right before it changes? Because your formula `currentPlaybackPositionMs / 1000 < 1` looks like the beginning of the track, which should be the next track.

Comment: Since I have set the REPEAT_MODE_ONE, the track would loop back to its initial state. So it the same track at the beginning

Comment: I see, but is there a way to make it pause at the end of the current track?

Comment: In that case,  you can store the timestamp of the media that is currently being played in this function "onPositionDiscontinuity".  And reset and run a counter till the end of the total media length. Keep the repeat mode as REPEAT_MODE_NONE. So everytime a track changes or is seeked onPositionDiscontinuity method will be called and your counter will be reset and run till the end of the media. And when it ends you can pause your media.

Answer (score 1):

Since `DefaultEventListener` and `onPlayerStateChanged()` are deprecated.

Use `Player.EventListener` and `onPlaybackStateChanged()`

**Kotlin code**:

```kotlin
 player!!.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
                if (state == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                    // your code here
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
      exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {

                  
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to listen to the end of media file using exoplayer.

The new Media3 ExoPlayer API provides [`onMediaItemTransition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/common/Player.Listener#onMediaItemTransition(androidx.media3.common.MediaItem,int)) callback for the transition between media items:

[Per documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/listening-to-player-events#playlist-transitions):

> Whenever the player changes to a new media item in the playlist
> onMediaItemTransition(MediaItem mediaItem, @MediaItemTransitionReason
> int reason) is called on registered Player.Listener objects. The
> reason indicates whether this was an automatic transition, a seek (for
> example after calling player.next()), a repetition of the same item,
> or caused by a playlist change (for example, if the currently playing
> item is removed).

Demo use:

```
val mediaTransitionListener = object : Player.Listener {
    override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
        super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)
        
        // Media Transition
        
    }
}

// register the listener 
exoPlayer.addListener(mediaTransitionListener)
```

And don't forget to remove the listener when you cleanup things to avoid memory leaks:

```
exoPlayer.removeListener(mediaTransitionListener)
```